# Passing arrays of urls in Curl request

Tags: php

I need to pass multiple url parameters to make a single CURL request. Not sure but whenever I use foreach loop it make calls only on the last url.

Here is my code

```
$urls = array(
  'https://example.com?id=346428437&league_id=35',
  'https://example.com?id=346428437&league_id=36',
  'https://example.com?id=346428437&league_id=37',
  'https://example.com?id=346428437&league_id=38',
  'https://example.com?id=346428437&league_id=39',
  'https://example.com?id=346428437&league_id=40'
);
foreach($urls as $uri){
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
if ($data === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
 }
curl_close($ch);
}
```

It appears to call only the last url.

Comment: _"It appears"_ - how do you test that? (`$data` will be overwritten in each call, so you'll only see the last result)

Comment: "`https://example.com&league_id=...`" is wrong syntax btw. should be "`https://example.com?league_id=...`"

Comment: @Jeff When i dump the data it prints the results of last url param.

Comment: now re-read my first comment.

Comment: Yes i know that. I forgot to put this in the post

Comment: @NigelRen I didn't knew that it was important to mark answer. Thanks for pointing. Finally I could get it working. Appreciate your help. cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a list of the data being passed back, at the moment you are just keeping the last one and overwriting it (`$data` is always set from `curl_exec()`).  Start by creating an empty array and add to it each time...

```
$output = [];    // Empty array
foreach($urls as $uri){
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
    if ($data === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . 
                     var_export($info));
    }
    $output [] = json_decode($data,true);   // Add new data to output
    curl_close($ch);
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: This looks solution but decoding doesn't work on this? $obj = json_decode($output, true);

foreach($obj['results'] as $result){

Comment: `$output` is an array - you could try `$output [] =  json_decode($data,true);` so you decode each return value as it comes back.  Also remember the `$output` is a list of results, so you will need to loop over the `$output` array and process each one at a time.

Comment: If you change the code to above, what do you get from `print_r($output);`?

Comment: I am getting normal json response of all urls which is perfect.. but while i decode, it just decode the last url param..

Comment: If you have changed the line `$output [] = json_decode($data,true);   // Add new data to output` I've updated in the answer, then `$output` should be all of the data json decoded.